# New Gmail fonts looks fuzzy

Tags: windows, google-chrome, firefox, gmail

Anyone knows how to "fix" the blurry font in the new Gmail UI without enabling Clear Type for the whole OS?

Chrome:

[image]

Firefox:

[image]

Comment: Clear Type works very well. Just enable it.

Comment: ClearType is specifically designed to minimize this effect. It's exploiting physical construction of LCDs to make edges sharper. Why are you disabling it?

Comment: @gronostaj I guess can "live" with it in Gmail only but I prefer non Clear Type fonts in the OS level.

Comment: Isn't this a DPI issue? Do you use a DPI that anything else than 100DPI?

Comment: @LPChip My DPI settings has always been default at 100%.